# Spiros in Chemfig

Tags: chemfig

[image]

Hello I need help: How to draw a spiro compound? Thanks for help me.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Just for this occasion I have completed your code...but I am not expert in Chemistry. Excuse me if I have done of the mistakes.

PS: You ask, generally, question where an user must to create your drawing.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\chemfig{
            % 9
     >[:270]% 5
     -[:270]% 4
               (
         -[:210]% 3
                   (
             -[:150]% 8
              -[:90]% 7
              -[:30]% 6
             -[:330]% -> 5
                   )
         -[:300]% 2
         -[:180]% 1
          -[:60]% -> 3
               )
               (
        <:[:270]% 15
               )
     -[:330]% 10
      -[:30]% 11
      -[:90]% 12
               (
          -[:30]COOCH_3% 14
               )
    =^[:150]% 13
               (
         -[:210]% -> 5
               )
}
\caption{Is this a Spiro compound??}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thanks!! I need to learn this, can you help me for skype?

Comment: write me please, help me.